# My c# application cannot connect to database on window7 64bit with microsoft access database engine 2010 32bit

Tags: ms-access, clickonce

I'm working with

1) Window7 32bit
2) VS 2005
3) language: C#

I made an application that connects to an Access file and deployed the applicatioin with Clickonce on my computer.

I published in release/any cpu mode.

The prerequisites was .Net Framework 2.0.

When I installed the appliction on another computer (Window7 64bit, MS Access Database Engine 2010 32bit), an error occurred.

The error message was `Cannot Connect to Database.... System.Data`.

My connection string is `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=...`.

Comment: Check your db path on installed PC, is file is there or not?

Answer (score 1):

64-bit and 32-bit components don't play well together.

I had a similar issue with 64-bit Windows and a 32-bit ODBC driver. You most likely need the 64-bit version of the Access database driver.

Comment: The drivers can be found here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255